# How can I remove an additional unwanted name from the answers i have received within a search in a specific table created within a dataset?

Tags: sql, datatable

I have tried to remove two unwanted answers from a table that I had created from certain data. However, once I add an additional name to remove, neither name is removed. Is there an option to remove more than one answer (in my case names) from the table?

Please take a look at the code:

```
SELECT
  person,
  COUNT(1) AS count_mentions,
  COUNT(DISTINCT url) AS count_distinct_urls
FROM
  `robust-cycle-309917.56146_2021_big_data.israel_media_person`
WHERE lower(person) not like '%gaza%' OR lower(person) not like '%Maccabi Haifa%'
GROUP BY
  person
ORDER BY
  count_mentions DESC
LIMIT
  10;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points

- If you need to remove both names then you should use "and" instead of "or"
- If you use the function lower() then it should be

  lower(person) not like '%maccabi haifa%'

instead of

```
lower(person) not like '%Maccabi Haifa%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause should use `AND` not `OR`

so

```
WHERE lower(person) not like '%gaza%' OR lower(person) not like '%Maccabi Haifa%'
```

Should be

```
WHERE lower(person) not like '%gaza%' AND lower(person) not like '%Maccabi Haifa%'
```

Comment: I had run the code with this answer and it had only lowered '%gaza%' and not '%Maccabi Haifa%' , is there a solution for this? or is there a larger problem within the code?

Answer (score 0):

> We must also remove the extra space on the right to match. Try this:

```
SELECT
  person,
  COUNT(1) AS count_mentions,
  COUNT(DISTINCT url) AS count_distinct_urls
FROM
  `robust-cycle-309917.56146_2021_big_data.israel_media_person`
WHERE
  LOWER(RTRIM(person)) NOT LIKE 'gaza gaza'
  AND LOWER(RTRIM(person)) NOT LIKE 'maccabi haifa'
GROUP BY
  person
ORDER BY
  count_mentions DESC
LIMIT
  10;

-- Result
--  person  count_mentions  count_distinct_urls
--  Benjamin Netanyahu  32,455  20,302
--  Reuben Castro   21,093  3,366
--  Donald Trump    13,643  7,728
--  Medinat Yisrael     12,372  8,894
--  Benny Gantz     10,551  5,542
--  Oz Muallem  10,514  3,860
--  Reuben Schwartz     9,232   3,631
--  Yedioth Ahronoth    8,587   4,401
--  Moshe Kahlon    8,480   6,521
--  Miri Regev  7,853   4,907
```